# Promise ReaddirSync not returning values

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have files in the directories,  the `let resolvers = { ...resolversArray[0], ...resolversArray[1] };` line does get set, however I'm trying to make it so I don't manually need to put in each item of the array.

Here is my code

```
let resolversArray = [];
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/modules`).forEach((folder) => {
    let temp = require(`./modules/${folder}/resolver.js`);
    resolversArray[folder] = temp;
  });
  if (resolversArray.length > 0) {
    resolve(resolversArray);
  } else {
    reject("Resolvers Array is empty");
  }
});
promise.then((array) => {
  console.log("returned array", resolversArray);
});
```

Result is I get a rejected promise with Resolvers Array is empty being returned.

Comment: Why do you need promises if it's sync?

Comment: And why are you using an array as if it was a plain object?

Comment: You're just adding properties to an array (not items, I mean literally properties, as you can do with every object). Of course, the `length` property won't update consequently.